# Coud not insert data in Mysql

Tags: mysql

So I have a table which contains two columns and one foreign key I don't know why but the foreign key is unknown by the SQL.

Here a screenshot to show the error and the table:

[image]

Comment: Post the structure of your table please

Comment: It has **two** columns, why you tried to insert **three** columns?

Comment: the third is foregin key it mention in a the image in the object browse

Comment: The `userid` under Foreign Keys is not a column name, it's a constraint name.

Answer (score 0):

In your table you have only two column `idcv` and `type` and you created a foreignKey on one of those column with the name `userid`. You need to have a actual column with name `userid` to be able to insert the data.

For example here `parent_id` is foreignkey

```sql
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT,
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```